# Why my library override disappears on file reload?

Tags: linked-data

I've been using library overlays with any troubles... until today. For some reasons, when I reload my file, one object loses the keyframes attached to it:

[image]

[image]

Save, and after reloading (either File > reload, or close/re-open blender):

[image]

Any idea what I got wrong? This appears with the 3 bezier curves from this collection. I tried to repeat this operation multiple times, always the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood the issue: my object was animated in the file I linked it from... I guess that Library overrides gets confused when an object is animated in the original file, so I just copied the object in a new file, removed the animations, and linked it from there.